# Error en el login de una webapp, no funciona el botón para iniciar sesión

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Lo siguiente es lo que me muestra en la consola:

```
[Mon Oct 23 2017 18:45:46 GMT-0500 (Hora de verano central (México))] #tickets 404 Not Found get /  Error: 404 Not Found get / 

    at Sammy.Application.error (sammy.js:1372)
    at Sammy.Application.notFound (sammy.js:1361)
    at Sammy.Application.runRoute (sammy.js:1198)
    at Sammy.Application._checkLocation (sammy.js:1391)
    at Sammy.Application.run (sammy.js:990)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):274)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/rest/login Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
(index):329 Object
```

Y en el log me da lo siguiente:

```
ERROR - 2017-10-23 19:48:01 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Admin_categorias_model /home/ielcjapo/public_html/app/system/core/Loader.php 344

ERROR - 2017-10-23 19:48:02 --> $config['composer_autoload'] is set to TRUE but /home/ielcjapo/public_html/app/application/vendor/autoload.php was not found.

ERROR - 2017-10-23 19:48:02 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Admin_categorias_model /home/ielcjapo/public_html/app/system/core/Loader.php 344

ERROR - 2017-10-23 19:48:02 --> $config['composer_autoload'] is set to TRUE but /home/ielcjapo/public_html/app/application/vendor/autoload.php was not found.

ERROR - 2017-10-23 19:48:02 --> Severity: error --> Exception: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Admin_categorias_model /home/ielcjapo/public_html/app/system/core/Loader.php 344
```

Answer (score 0):

El Framework no puede encontrar los modulos configura correctamente `$autoload['model']` o revisa los permisos para ver si apache tiene acceso a los archivos.

Comment: en donde puedo encontrar esta variable?

Comment: debes tener un archivo llamado **autoload.php**